# Yii-framework Encoding

Tags: yii, encoding

Why when unpacking archives yii framework of the archive with the console prompt:

```
cd c: \
cd WebServers \ home \ y1 \ www \ framework
php -f yiic webapp C: \ WebServers \ home \ y1 \ www
```

Encoding all files Ansi, when should be utf-8?

Answer (score 0):

It's because Windows uses [an ANSI-like encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). It shouldn't cause too much trouble unless you start writing with special charaters like: ñ,á,è... and then upload those files to a non-windows server.

A workaround is use a good text-editor, like Notepad++ or Sublime Text, and then force the encoding to UTF-8.